# Undefined offset using fopen csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Hey guys im having a problem with a script im working on. 
Im getting two errors and i dont understand why.

I do know that the csv file is csv comma delimited type.

**Errors**

> Notice: Undefined variable: data in /home1/public_html/tickets/inv.php on line 17
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /home1/public_html/tickets/inv.php on line 20

Here is a link to my csv file: http://goo.gl/tcNNm1

```
//connect to the database 
$connect = mysql_connect("*****","*********","*******"); 
mysql_select_db("don=_scanner",$connect); //select the table 
// 

   $file =  "rfl2.csv";
   $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 


    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO inv (stk, vin) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

I had this script working with a file i upload through a forum but im trying to make it load that one file when i request the page.

Comment: use `while() {}` instead of `do {} while()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong kind of loop. `$data` will not be defined until after the FIRST iteration of the loop, because the `$data = fgetcsv()` will not be executed until the do/while's innards have been run once already.

You want

```
while($data = fgetcsv(...)) {
   ... database insert ...
}
```

instead

Plus, you are vulnerable to sql injection attacks. `addslashes` is utterly useless for protection against this. At least use the proper `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

`while(...) {...}` - execute loop contents only if the condition is true
`do {...} while(...)` - execute loop contents at least once, terminate if condition is false

Comment: Something like this? 

`$file =  "rfl.csv";

   $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 
     

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    while($data = fgetcsv($file)) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO inv (stk, vin) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); `

Comment: don't post code blocks in a comment. it's utterly unreadable.

Comment: Sorry Kinda new here :(

Comment: No problem. you can edit your question and append the new code.

Comment: it said it could not be edited after 5 min.  so i am reposting...    
$file =  "rfl.csv";
   $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 
     

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    while($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO inv (stk, vin) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));

Answer (score 0):

As the property of `Do-While` , it runs at least once. `So at first iteration, $data variable is undefined.` hence error!. Possible solution is do something like:
`if(isset($data))` instead of if($data). or better go for `while loop` or `for loop`.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
 while(!feof($handle)){
            $values = fgetcsv( $handle);

            if(isset($values[0])){
            add sql here..


            }
        }
```

Comment: While this code may address the OP's issue, it is better to include an explanation of what the code does, why it solves the problem, and why this is a better answer than the others provided.